# How to change every Vertex`s color dynamically acoording to time or some function?

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to draw a 2D contour of Gaussian function(Z=f(x,y,sigma)) . x,y is the Vertex`s x,y;z=0. i get a color of every vertex using Z. While sigma is changed bewteen 0.01-1.0 ,Z and color value will change. how to update color?

```
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GaussianVertexices), GaussianVertexices,    GL_STATIC_DRAW);//GaussianVertexices contains Pos and Color;
//...
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    GaussShader.use();
    sigma += 0.01;
    if (sigma>1.0)
    {
        sigma = 0.1;
    }
    // how can i update color value with sigma changed
    glBindVertexArray(GaussVAO);
    glPointSize(2.0f);
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, POINTS_NUMS);
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}
```

vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core
layout(location=0) in vec2 apos;
layout(location=1) in vec3 acolor;

out vec3 color;


void main()
{
    gl_Position=vec4(apos.x,apos.y,0.0,1.0f);
    color=acolor;
}
```

fragment shader

```
#version 330 core
in vec3 color;
out vec4 fragColor;

void main()
{
    fragColor=vec4(color,0.5);
}
```

update：
i tried it in this.

```
 while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {//....
        GaussShader.use();
        sigma += 0.01;
        CreateGuassColor(GaussVertexices, GaussColor);
        if (sigma>1.0)
        {
            sigma = 0.01;
        }

        glBindVertexArray(GaussVAO);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ColorVBO);
        void *ptr = nullptr;
          ptr  = glMapBufferRange(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(GaussColor), GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT);

        memcpy(ptr, GaussColor, sizeof(GaussColor));
        glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
        glBindVertexArray(GaussVAO);
        glPointSize(2.0f);
        glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, POINTS_NUMS);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
uniform vec4 vertexColor;
```

to your fragment shader.

Make sure you get the ID of your shader program when you first create it. This is before you even compile and link your vertex and fragment shader. You do it like:

```
GLuint gaussShaderProg = glCreateProgram();
```

then do:

```
GLint uniformLocation = glGetUniformLocation(gaussShaderProg, "vertexColor");
```

Then in your loop:

```
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    sigma += 0.01;
    if (sigma>1.0)
    {
        sigma = 0.1;
    }

    GaussShader.use(); // Make sure the shader program is 
                       // bound before trying to     update the uniform

    float vertColor[] = { 1, 1, 1, 1 }; // Whatever colour you want
    glUniform4fv(uniformLocation​, 1, (GLfloat*)vertColor​); // Now your fragment shader 
                                         // can access the updated colour


    glBindVertexArray(GaussVAO);
    glPointSize(2.0f);
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, POINTS_NUMS);
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}
```

Then in your fragment shader just output the uniform colour (the vec4). Make sure sure the fourth component of the colour is 1, just in case you have alpha blending on.

Comment: i have tried this. the uniform  only pass one color.not evey color of all points. so all points have  same color.

Comment: @JackChen Yes, the way I gave you sets one colour. If you want to give a different colour to each vertex, then there's two ways to do it that I know of. One way is to pack the vertex colour in as an attribute along with the others such as position and normal, and texcoords, and every time you render you upload the new set of vertices which contain the new colours.  The other way is to decide what colour each vertex has either in the shader, more likely vertex shader. If the colour is based on your sigma variable, then you only have that sigma variable as the uniform.

Comment: @JackChen Each time you draw you update the sigma so that the shaders have access to it, and in the shader calculate what colour the vertex will have based on the sigma value and its position. I'm sorry if this is irrelevant because I'm not really sure what it is you want to do.

Comment: I calculate the color based on the sigma and Z.thus I can see the impact of sigma. like the video show [2D Gaussian](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sim-Chen/OpenGL/DataVisualization/2DGaussianFuction/2DGaussianFunction/2DGaussianFunction/GuassFunction2D.mp4).I  modify [mycode](https://github.com/Sim-Chen/OpenGL/blob/DataVisualization/2DGaussianFuction/2DGaussianFunction/2DGaussianFunction/2DGaussianFunction.cpp).but can't get the effect .